# Anti-holomorphic derivative on 1/z

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, greens-function, greens-theorem

We know the fact that $\partial_{\bar z} (1/z) \propto \delta(z, \bar z)$. But I am slightly confused about the proof. I have seen a few of them, and of course they use the Green's theorem, or the Stokes' theorem,

$$\int_D \partial_{\bar z}\frac{ 1 }{ z } dz\wedge d\bar z \sim \int_{\partial D} \frac{ 1 }{ z } dz \ .$$

But if I understand correctly, these two theorems requires the integrand $1/z$ on the right to have continuous derivative, or roughly speaking the integrand on the left should have some sort of continuous property.

**So I wonder why these two theorems still hold/are effective in this case? Do the two theorems admit generalization to handle some singularities like this one?**

Comment: Pardon my ignorance: What is $\propto$ and $\delta(z, \bar z)$ ?

Comment: @MartinR They mean "proportional to" and the two dimensional delta function.